# ValueError: Expected object or value in pandas using lines=True

Tags: python, json, pandas

my test_data.json file format is

```
[{"Gender": "Male", "HeightCm": 171, "WeightKg": 96 },
{ "Gender": "Male", "HeightCm": 161, "WeightKg": 85 },
{ "Gender": "Male", "HeightCm": 180, "WeightKg": 77 },
{ "Gender": "Female", "HeightCm": 166, "WeightKg": 62},
{"Gender": "Female", "HeightCm": 150, "WeightKg": 70},
{"Gender": "Female", "HeightCm": 167, "WeightKg": 82}]
```

when I read the json file in panda using

```
basePath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
reader=pd.read_json(basePath+'/test_data.json',orient="records")
```

It converted json file in the perfect dataframe i.e.

```
   Gender  HeightCm  WeightKg
0    Male       171        96
1    Male       161        85
2    Male       180        77
3  Female       166        62
4  Female       150        70
5  Female       167        82
```

but now when i put the lines=True in the pd.read_json() i.e.

```
basePath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
reader=pd.read_json(basePath+'/test_data.json',orient="records",lines=True)
```

its generating the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 5, in <module>
    reader=pd.read_json(basePath+'/test_data.json',orient="records",lines=True)
  File "/home/king_leo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 207, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/king_leo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/king_leo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 614, in read_json
    return json_reader.read()
  File "/home/king_leo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 746, in read
    obj = self._get_object_parser(self._combine_lines(data_lines))
  File "/home/king_leo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 770, in _get_object_parser
    obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
  File "/home/king_leo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 885, in parse
    self._parse_no_numpy()
  File "/home/king_leo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 1164, in _parse_no_numpy
    loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Comment: You have different file names does `test_data.json` exist ?

Comment: yes its exist thats why without lines=True it generate the dataframe